# Does a mutex lock apply to functions called after locking?

Tags: c++, multithreading, directx, mutex

I'm trying to make a DirectX renderer for my game. I've heard that multi-threading is the best practice for optimization, so I'm trying my hand. I've got a basic renderer down, and I'm implementing multi-threading. So as the title says, Does a `std::mutex` lock apply to called functions?

```
void DXRenderer::draw(IDirect3DDevice9* _device) {
    mutex.lock();

    for (const DXCalls::DXCall call : safeCalls) {
        switch (call.type) {
            case DXCalls::DXCallType::FRECT:
                drawFRect(call.FRect);
                break;

            case DXCalls::DXCallType::RECT:
                drawRect(call.Rect);
                break;

            case DXCalls::DXCallType::LINE:
                drawLine(call.Line);
                break;

            case DXCalls::DXCallType::NONE:
                // do literally nothing
                break;

            default:
                MessageBoxA(NULL, "Invalid DXCallType, has a new type not been added to the loop?", "Debug", MB_OK);
                break;
        }
    }

    mutex.unlock();
}
```

As an example, if 2 threads called `DXRenderer::draw()`, would both threads call `drawFRect` or would it wait until the mutex has been unlocked?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. A mutex synchronizes two threads when those threads use the same mutex. I'm not sure what you are asking about "apply to called functions".

Comment: Multithreading is full of subtle traps and is one of the hardest things to get right. When you get it wrong, you usually won't see the problem appear right away. Instead, your program may rarely and randomly crash or freeze, resulting in an extremely difficult debugging situation. Multithreading should be learned from a formal source like a book or a class.

Comment: It looks like your synchronization solution locks a single mutex for the entire process of rendering. In this case, you will not gain any performance benefits from multithreading. One thread will own the mutex and render everything while every other thread will wait for it to finish. You will be paying the cost of initializing threads and synchronizing but without any benefits.

Comment: Directly calling `mutex.lock()` is discouraged. If an exception occurs while you own the lock, the lock will leak. You should use [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) or `std::lock_guard` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As an example, if 2 threads called DXRenderer::draw(), would both threads call drawFRect

No, because only 1 thread at a time can hold the lock on the mutex.

> would it wait until the mutex has been unlocked?

Yes.  That is the whole point of a mutex.  Once a thread owns the lock on a mutex, any other thread that tries to obtain the lock to the same mutex will wait until the owning thread unlocks it.

And FYI, you should not be calling `lock()` and `unlock()` manually, use [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) (or similar RAII helper) instead, eg:

```cpp
void DXRenderer::draw(IDirect3DDevice9* _device) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    // do work as needed...
} // <-- automatically unlocks here
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thread which calls the draw function locks the mutex, performs the job and then unlock the mutex. The second thread if calls the draw function shall wait for mutex to get unlock by first thread.
Only one thread can access the critical section(code between mutex lock and unlock) at a given instance of time. Here function can be called by number of threads, but only one thread can access the critical section at any point of time; rest all have to wait